# Create method with access to similar named field, but different types of object without inheritance

Tags: c#

Create method with access to similar named field, but different types of object without inheritance in c#.

For ex. I have 2 Classes:

```
      public class MyClass1
      {
          public int Id { get; set; }
      }
      public class MyClass2
      {
          public int Id { get; set; }
      }
```

And I need to create method and pass to it instance of each Classes:

```
    DoStuff(new MyClass1());
    DoStuff(new MyClass2());
```

And Method will be like this:

```
    private void DoStuff<T>(T obj)
    {
        int i = obj.Id(); // here is the problem
    }
```

Yes, problem is, that `obj` can't resolve `Id`. Solution simple - create `RootClass` with `Id` property, and use `public class MyClass1: RootClass`... , but I can't do this.

Question is: Can I use line like   `int i = obj.Id();` without creating `RootClass`?

**Edit:** I need answers like: 
 No, because.... or 
 Yes, do this.....

Comment: This is typically why `interfaces` exist: Describe a common contract, but with no relationship between the classes. Do you have access to the source of the class? Can you change it ? I would suggest you to create a `public interface IHasId { int Id { get; set; } }` if you can

Comment: @SteveB, Yes, I can add misc changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is typically why interfaces exist: describe a common contract, but with no relationship between the classes.

I would suggest you to create this interface

```
public interface IHasId { 
    int Id { get; set; } 
} 


  public class MyClass1 : IHasId
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
  }
  public class MyClass2 : IhasId
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
  }


...


private void DoStuff<T>(T obj) 
    where T : IHasId // constraint my be moved to the class declaration
{
    int i = obj.Id();
}
```

Creating this interface will let you avoid introducing a root class, which may be not desired if the classes has no root behavior.

Comment: Thanks, for fast answer - that's what I want. Wait 10 minutes and I accept it.